# Heroku Deploy failed due to Postgresql Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm having a problem with my Archives built on Ruby on Rails when I deploy to Heroku. Everything is working fine on my Local servers however when I run the app on Heroku there are problems when i load the page.

The Heroku logs showed this

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
```

Comment: Is Heroku's Postgres using the same version as yours? Do you have all the same extensions enabled?

Comment: I just checked Heroku's Postgres is running an earlier version than mine. How would I check the other extensions installed?

Comment: I think it might be the version that's at fault, then. Can you please post the part of your code that uses `strftime`? It doesn't seem to be widely supported in Postgres, but it may be a very recent addition; and it might be an idea to see if you can refactor it on your end instead.

Comment: I use it in multiple places. But an example of that is like this.

 `@bets_by_month = @bets_by_year.where("strftime('%m', created_at) = ?", params[:month])`

Comment: In that particular case, you may want to use `.where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) = ?", params[:month])`. `EXTRACT` goes back at least as far as 9.0. See [the Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT). Or `date_part` is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forgot to run migration on heroku. just do
`heroku run rake db:migrate`